# FineUploader basic qqfile customization

Tags: fine-uploader

When fineUploader is initialized with a button option, it creates an input file within the button element, with `title="fineUploader"`, how do I change it. FineUploader doesn't have an onInitialize event or similar, so I don't know when to listen to a event and change the inputs title value.

```
<input style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family:Arial; 
font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0; 
height: 100%;" name="qqfile" multiple="" title="file input" 
qq-button-id="39e4cc96-00a2-47c6-a261-752fe0bbdae8" type="file">
```

Comment: Have you tried mutating the element after constructing a new instance of fine uploader?

Comment: I did, and it worked, but fineuploader keeps changing it back. Core type should be the most customizable but it left out certain parts. I have to keep changing it in onComplete event.

Comment: There is [an open case to address this](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1526). Can you take a look? I'll start working on that at once at hope to push out a new release, 5.6.0, with that adjustment soon. If you can verify that my adjustment addresses your issue, that will speed things up. Please comment on the referenced case, and I will update this question on SO with an answer once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Exactly the problem! I'll check in the issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader 5.6 allows you to customize the underlying file input element's `title` attribute. From [the release notes](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2016/03/24/fine-uploader-5-6-a-more-flexible-api/):

> ...a [text.fileInputTitle option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#text.fileInputTitle) was added. This allows the “title” attribute of the file input element managed by Fine Uploader to be customized. The title attribute can be customized via a new [“fileInputTitle” property on the “extraButtons” option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#extraButtons.fileInputTitle) when creating an [extra button](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/extra-buttons.html) as well. This completed a request detailed in case [#1526](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1526).